# Using grep in multiple directory/subdirectory and filtering out results?

Tags: grep

I'm using Terminal to list all the files that contain a word or a specific string of text. The files are basically pdf's in 3-4 folders in different locations.

When using the command in a single location it works

```
grep -wirl 'text-to-be-searched" ./
```

But if I try to get the number of results in each file using c:

```
grep -wirlc 'text-to-be-searched' ./
```

It shows "1" result in a file that has over 30 text-to-be-searched results and it includes files that are in the directory but have "0" results, how can I filter those out?

In addition, How can I can do this search in all directories at the same time?

Edit 1: Tried this grep using a whole sentence as it is in a pdf file to confirm that grep works but it does not give the result, it can't find it. Why??

Comment: Try it after removing the `l` from the options.

Comment: Thanks, it worked out. Is there a way to hide the ones with no results?

Comment: Add another filter to filter them out: `| grep -v ':0$'`. So `grep -wirc 'text-to-be-searched' ./ | grep -v ':0$'`.

Comment: Do `man grep` for more info.